# Error running Tensorflow code on Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, debugging, tensorflow

I ran my code on a Windows system and it worked fine. I am now trying to run it on an Ubuntu machine and I get the following error:

```
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/input_0, import/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights)
     [[Node: import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/input_0, import/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/user/HS127/sc00858/Documents/tensorflow-for-poets-2/scripts/test.py", line 118, in <module>
    {input_operation.outputs[0]: t})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/input_0, import/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights)
     [[Node: import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/input_0, import/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights)]]

Caused by op u'import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution', defined at:
  File "/user/HS127/sc00858/Documents/tensorflow-for-poets-2/scripts/test.py", line 85, in <module>
    graph = load_graph(model_file)
  File "/user/HS127/sc00858/Documents/tensorflow-for-poets-2/scripts/test.py", line 38, in load_graph
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 288, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/input_0, import/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights)
     [[Node: import/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/convolution = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/input_0, import/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights)]]
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring and any help in debugging would be appreciated. My code is trying to run inference on a pre-trained mobilenet graph.

**EDIT**

Minimum of TF 1.5 is needed to infer from Mobilenet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to put my money on a Tensorflow version mismatch. Based on the following error text:

```
NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op
```

Dilated convolutions are a rather newish concept, and likely to be changing from minor version to minor version, and it sounds like your code is utilizing it in a function, perhaps in the layers api. Check that you're running the same tensorflow version on both systems. If they're not the same version, look for the term `dilations` in your code as the likely culprit of change.

Comment: Thank you, it did appear to be that!